# How to transform a report that is not a table format into a table format with Python

Tags: python-3.x, automation

I've been struggling a while trying to solve the following issue.

I have some reports in .txt format that in the first 3 rows the metadata is placed, then, the report is displayed as a normal table.

[Report Layout viewed in excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCQF7.png)

Because of the layout of the report i have to use the following code to read the file

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('R1.txt', sep='delimiter',header=None)
```

I use `sep='delimiter'` because my .txt file is tabular separated file. getting the following:[dataframe after reading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhXqM.png)

how can I take only the "dates" value and have it repeated along into a new column? having this i can erase the metadata rows so i can have the dataframe layout as a table. see example
[desired dataframe layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/677p0.png)

Answer (score 0):

if your separator is a tabular you should use the following

```py
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('R1.txt', sep='\t',header=None)
```